# Cannot set text field value after selecting suggestion from typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-typeahead

I cannot set the value for a text field after selecting (twitter) typeahead suggestion

This does not work:

```
  $("#location").on("typeahead:selected", function(eventObject, suggestion, name) {
  console.log(suggestion.stop_id);
  $("#location").val(suggestion.stop_id);
});
```

While this works: (but I want text entered in same text field)

```
  $("#location").on("typeahead:selected", function(eventObject, suggestion, name) {
  console.log(suggestion.stop_id);
  $("#destination").val(suggestion.stop_id);
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code on how you are initializing typehead? If you are using location as your typehead target why you wanted to assign the value again?

Comment: https://paste.opensuse.org/35736889 I'm trying to change content of text field having id=location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to replace return null with return suggestion.value in display parameter function of typeahead to put desired value in field.